# Storing sql database in cloud

Tags: android, database

I’m making an app where users can provide their service and set a custom asking price. I will need to store they’re login information, location and price info in a database on a server, so all users that are using the app can locate other users that provide these services.

I don’t really want to spend time setting up my own server and would rather store the database in the cloud. 
The only free one (for a certain amount of data) I’ve found so far is parse https://parse.com/docs/android/guide.

Would it be possible to store it in Dropbox or could there be possible syncing issues if multiple people access it simultaneously?

Comment: While I did post an answer comment below, do take into account that there is enormous amounts of information online on this subject and you should review those, before asking in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Amazon AWS free tier if you wanted to:  http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Drop-box isn't designed for the purpose you describe and the authentication credentials would have to be embedded in your app and disseminated to every client that installed it.  This isn't wise.

Personally, I'd use AWS free tier and stand up a small relational DB to hold your service/pricing info.

Comment: I would add, use AWS RDS; combined with EC2 over ElasticBeanstalk you can do a very simple setup that still falls under the free tier.